# MySql desde Java con ResultSet Scroll_Sensitive

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Estoy utilizando el conector JDBC de MySQL 5.1.26 y, si consulto los metadatos, me indica que no admite los cursores Scroll_Sensitive:

```
Connection con;
try {
    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/miBD", "root", "");
    DatabaseMetaData metadata = con.getMetaData();

    boolean soportaScroolSensitive = 
     metadata.supportsResultSetType(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE);
```

La llamada a este último método me devuelve falso. Ahora bien, si creo un Statement indicando que quiero un cursor de ese tipo, compruebo que sí que lo admite:

```
Statement stmt = con.createStatement(
            ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,
            ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);

ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Clientes;");

rs.last();
while (rs.previous())
    System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
```

El bucle itera perfectamente los registros desde el final hasta el inicio.

¿Por qué el método supportsResultSetType() de metadata me indica que no soporta este tipo de cursor cuando realmente sí que lo hace?

Answer (score 1):

Es posible que hayas obtenido un ResultSet de tipo TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE:
Un ResultSet "scrollable" se puede recorrer en ambos sentidos, pero hay dos tipo de "scrollable": sensitive e "insensitive". De la [documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/ResultSet.html) (las negritas son mías):

> ```
> static final int TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE
> ```
>
> The constant indicating the type for a ResultSet object that is
> scrollable but generally not sensitive to changes to the data that
> underlies the ResultSet.
>
> ```
> static final int TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE
> ```
>
> The constant indicating the type for a ResultSet object that is scrollable and **generally
> sensitive to changes** to the data that underlies the ResultSet.

Comment: Pablo,  link a la documentación esta roto.

Comment: Pero yo pregunto si admite SENSITIVE y me responde que no. En cambio después compruebo que sí que lo es.

Comment: @MitaCloud Le faltaba un caracter, arreglado! Gracias por avisar

Comment: @Alberto Es *sensitive* o es simplemente *scrollable*? Por lo que estoy leyendo [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23817619/mysql-resultset-scrollable-updatable-not-working-as-expected) parece MySQL siempre permite usar `rs.previous()`, incluso aunque no lo pidamos.